# How to run crontab for Magento upgrade

Tags: magento2, crontab

I am having a problem with crontab I installed Magento on DigitalOcean using one-click approach and it's working fine but I want to upgrade Magento to the last version 2.1.5 and Check Readiness gives me a problem with crontab inside my crontab is:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and the content is:

```
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command

* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/html/magento/var/log/mage$
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

Magento path:

```
/var/www/html/magento
```

the problem that I'm having is:

[image]